# Microsoft Azure change from geo redundant to local redundant

Tags: azure

I have recently brought Microsoft Azure product for storage purpose of a NAS.

At first i chose the "read access geo redundant" and made a schedule for my NAS to backup. 
Today i have changed it to local redundant (i saw the price difference) but my synology NAS is not finished backing up yet. Will it automaticly change to local redundant, or should i cancel the backup and re-do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you don't have to do anything. Azure will automatically convert your storage account's redundancy type from `RAGRS` to `LRS`.

To elaborate more, essentially the way RAGRS works is that data is written to the primary storage account and then through some background process the data is replicated to the secondary storage account. Once you change the redundancy to LRS, the replication stops.

One more point I would like to mention. If you're storing your data in blob storage for backup purpose only, may I suggest that you look at [`Cool Storage`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introducing-azure-cool-storage/) offering from Azure Storage. Compared to standard storage accounts, cost of storing data in a `Cool Storage` account is much lesser.

Comment: Great thansk a lot :-) 
I am already running cool storage as i dont need the data, only for backup if our NAS gets stolen or something.